# How to retrieve Google + Circle contact in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am an Android newbie. I am developing an App that allows users to send messages to each other.

I am able to retrieve contact list and pictures in Android but I think the list is not enough. Is it possible to retrieve contacts in Google Plus circle? I do have some researches but cannot find any clues.

Also, do I need to register People API to get Circle contacts? If yes, can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:What your contact list data came from?
Q2:if you want to get a SNS platform info, you need add the sdk to your app on usual

Comment: my contact list data is from Contact API. However, I think it does not have enough email addresses that I used to interact with on Gplus. Therefore, I want to get more via People API.

Comment: here is the contact that I want to retrieve
http://2.pik.vn/201695f7ea7e-58ec-4ead-a015-6823a480e4bf.jpg

I tried People API, however, when I run the line

List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();

the connections is always null

Comment: you can debug and get response info.see what is in response.one by one.you must find the question and solution